# How copy content of minibuffer to kill-ring?

Tags: minibuffer, copy-paste, kill-ring

Windows 10, Emacs 25, Helm

How copy content of minibuffer to kill-ring?

Answer (score 5):

Just like ordinary buffers, <kbd>C-x h</kbd> (`mark-whole-buffer`) then <kbd>M-w</kbd> (`kill-ring-save`).

Comment: Not work. If I use command (mark-whole-buffer) then mark buffer that is in focus. E.g. *scratch*. And as result mark all *scratch* buffer.

Comment: Try placing point in the minibuffer with `C-x o` and follow xuchunyang suggestion.

Comment: @Alex: It works for me, with vanilla Emacs (no init file): `emacs -Q`. Perhaps there is something in your init file that causes trouble. Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Yes I have same problem when start Emacs by Emacs -Q. Press "C-x o" is not help. "C-x h" also not help.

Comment: @Alex Launch Emacs via `emacs -Q` and type `M-: hello world`, now to copy "hello world", type `C-x h M-w`. I don't see what could be not working. or maybe I misunderstood your question?